# Recarregar a pagina no vue 3 no dist não acha a pagina

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Criando uma aplicação simples no vue3 cli e entrando na pagina router ele me da esse codigo ->

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

const routes = [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/about',
  name: 'About',
  // route level code-splitting
  // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
  // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ 
   '../views/About.vue')
 }
 ]

 const router = createRouter({
   history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
   routes
  })

  export default router
```

o problema e: Quando eu dou um npm run build no console, ele me retorna um dist e quando eu coloco o dist no server apache2 e entro na pagina, ele funciona perfeitamente a primeiro momento. Quando eu entro na pagina /about pelo menu ele funciona mas se eu continuar na pagina /about e recarregar a pagina, ele da um erro 404, alguem sabe como arrumar?

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations. Ou podes tentar com `mode:'hash'` para testar.

Comment: Cara, eu ja testei do mode:'hash' e deu certo, mas queria uma solução que não usasse isso. 
Tb tentei criar o .htaccess com o codigo que tem nesse link mas tb não deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema colocando no **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

dentro do virutalHost

e ativando o mod_rewrite usando o comando

```
a2enmod rewrite
```